# Files upload using ajax returns error but files submitted normally on server side in asp.net using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a asp.net form that uses ajax for form submit and when I click the button that uploads the files, the alert message in the error in jQuery is being displayed, but when I check the files on the server, the files are being uploaded with no problem.

Note: If I submit many files with large files, not all files will be submitted.

client page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewForm_Frontend_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="eformsmanagementtool.NewForm_Frontend_test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
    <button id="btnUpload">Click</button>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="True" />
    </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#btnUpload").click(function (event) {
                alert("Script Started")
                var files = $("#FileUpload1")[0].files;
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                    }
                    alert("Number of files: " + files.length)
                    formData.append("Name", "John");
                    alert("Before ajax")
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'NewForm_Backend_test.aspx',
                        timeout: 30000,
                        data: formData,
                        method: 'post',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (msg) {
                            alert("Good")
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert("Bad")
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Server side page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace eformsmanagementtool
{
    public partial class NewForm_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
            string data = Request.Form["Name"];

            Response.Write("You've submitted: " + data);
            HttpFileCollection files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(fileName);
                    Response.StatusCode = 200;
                }

                else
                {
                    file.SaveAs(fileName);
                    Response.StatusCode = 200;
                }
            }
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/json");
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PROBLEM RESOLVED]

I had to add `async: false` to ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'NewForm_Backend_test.aspx',
    async: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    data: formData,
    method: 'post',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("Good")
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("Bad")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your form attributes : enctype="multipart/form-data">